# Installing Software/Games

Tags: apt, games, downloads

First, I am new to Ubuntu and have never used any Linux operating system before.  I have removed Windows from all of my PCs and am trying something different.

The first question I have is really about installing games.  I already have steam (very user friendly) so I have no problems there.  I want to play Urban Terror which I downloaded from their site, but I don't know how to install the package from there.  I found a way through terminal, which was going okay, downloading at 2.8Mb/s to start now it dropped 2,888PB/s, which is going to take forever.

Attached are some pictures, so you can see what I have, what I am doing, and the problems I am having.

[image: file]

[image: downloading]

Comment: Well, 2888 PB/s would be insanely fast, as it's 2888 Petabytes/second. So clearly there is an issue there. Tried stopping and restarting the install?

Comment: Please post textual information as text and not as images. It's much more accessible and searchable.

Comment: It looks like the package repository is just slow at the moment. Try again later or find a mirror for the repository.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the package repository (`archive.getdeb.net`) is just slow at the moment. I experienced similar problems with it in the past.

Try again later or find a mirror for the repository.

Answer (score -4):

Hi there when i was new to ubuntu i had tried a software called wine check for it in the ubuntu software center you will find it there using that you can install the windows application also just give it a try

Comment: Thanks I finally got it to download I have heard of wine but have yet to explore it. I was just wondering if there was a universal command for terminal for installing downloaded games or software that where for linux.

Comment: wine is pretty straightforward just use the game's installer to install and you will find your games in $HOME/.wine/

Comment: @ShantanuBedajna Urban Terror is a native game. Wine is not needed. Please review your question.